# Husserl and Science

Tags: philosophy-of-science, husserl

If Husserl is not concerned with proving that the external world exists unlike Descartes then how does his findings on the nature of consciousness help to provide indubitable foundations for all sciences?

Comment: Existence of the external world is not the foundation of sciences, it might, ideally, be their conclusion. The *foundation* is that which is *directly given* in experience, and mixing in preconceived notions would only compromise their grounding, making it logically circular. This is why the first order of business is to bracket out the external world, and much else, in the phenomenological reduction. The phenomenological attitude that delivers the foundation must *suspend* presuppositions of the natural attitude to do its work.

Comment: Does science need to establish the existence of the external world? Even if there is no external world but our consciousness is seeing ghosts (a la Spinoza), we could still have a science of those "ghosts".

Comment: I still think Lukacs makes the most interesting critique.  https://www.marxists.org/archive/lukacs/works/1949/existentialism.htm